# Which stack is has file libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so?

Tags: ros, kinect, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running simulation TurtleBot (roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch) and taking error "Failed to load libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so: libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Where is that file to find?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11083/which-stack-is-has-file-libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so?/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it's in [gazebo_plugins](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/electric/gazebo_plugins), starting with electric.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-11-28**:
And for ones that are still in diamondback there is a possible solution to work this out??